# mysql 5.1.73 load data local infile error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to load data into a mysql table using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE using the code below.

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'unziped/product.csv' INTO TABLE producttemp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

Until couple days ago this my script was working fine but then hosting company is updated mysql to 5.1.73 and now im geting error "The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version".

I dont know what version was before on server.This command also works fine on mysql 5.3 and 5.5

What can be problem here?

I tried to google but cant find any similar problem

Comment: Do you run that command from `PHP` code? If yes, what PHP extension do you use for communication with the database (mysql/mysqli/PDO)?

Comment: And if you're not running it from PHP, why are you using the PHP tag?

Answer (score 1):

If you run that command from `PHP` code, the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` command can be enabled on the connection to the MySQL server.

The exact procedure depends on the PHP extension used for communication with MySQL.

#### Using the old, deprecated, `mysql` extension:

Put `128` into the parameter `$flags` of `mysql_connect()`, `OR`-ed, as usual, with other `MYSQL_CLIENT_*` flags you may need. The value `128` enables `LOAD DATA LOCAL` handling but there is no constant defined for it.
Read the documentation page for [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

```
// Put your connection parameters in $server, $username, $password as usual
$server   = '127.0.0.1';
$username = 'root';
$password = '****';
// Put 128 bitwise OR-ed with other flags, if needed
$flags = 128;
// ... and connect
$link = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password, $new_link, $flags);
```

#### Using the `mysqli` extension:

Use the [`mysqli_options()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php) function to set `MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE` to `TRUE`:

```
$link = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($link, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, TRUE);
mysqli_real_connect($server, $username, $password);
```

As it is explained in the documentation, this is the correct way to use `mysqli_options()`.

#### Using `PDO`:

Set the option [`PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) to `TRUE` on `$options` parameter of the `PDO` constructor:

```
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE = TRUE;
);
$link = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
```

Comment: Its a php script  and im using mysql. @axiac I tried your solution for mysql exstension, but still geting same message. I cant see or change my.conf

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the default settings in /etc/my.conf changed
There's a flag that should be set to make that work again:

```
local-infile = 1
```

You could als try to connect via commandline and explicitley set the flag:

```
mysql --local-infile -u root -p db_name
```